# Separating values with lines, not semicolons

Tags: list-view

I apologize if this was asked already, but I do not understand coding and am only working with SharePoint through an internet browser.  I am making a list and have a field where I can select multiple look-up values which are listed in the final list.  Unfortunately, the values look cluttered and are difficult to work with because they are simply separated by a semicolon rather than being on another line, which would make sense with that list item being usually at least 5 lines.  Is there a way to change the settings so each look-up name would appear on a different line?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2013? Maybe Client Side Rendering (JSLink) will help achieve that..

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to change how lookup values are stored within a field. That is how it works it uses an id for the value and semicolons to separate the values.